# How to run python program from command line with a program name and no path?

Tags: command-line, command, command-line-interface

I'm going to make a Git automation program with Python as a little side-project.To do this I'd like to be able to **run it from the command line with a name**, just like Git does. **I'm using Windows.** On UNIX devices you can make a shell script. How could I do that on Windows and run it with a program name?

For example, all of Git's commands can be done with the program executable `git`. If I wanted to do this how would I?

I looked through google but maybe I'm not searching for it correctly because I couldn't find anything.

Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: That's not a *keyword*. It's a program name. `git.exe` is the name of the program, and on Windows `git` is assumed to be an executable file by the OS.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks a lot, how could I create one of my own? (an executable file on the os)

Comment: You could start by searching this site for *python to exe*. Then you'll need to see how to add the location of your executable to the PATH (also asked here many times before).

Comment: Alright, thanks @KenWhite. I'm pretty new to CLI's and I have no idea where to look. Thanks for helping me through this one. Once I research the topics you suggested I'll post the solution back here. Thanks!

Comment: @KenWhite One more thing that I was wondering was how I could pass in arguments from the command line, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Search *python command line parameters*

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your time, you helped me tons.

Comment: Oh, one last thing @KenWhite will this still work if it is a `.exe` file?

Comment: You could make an effort to try something befoe asking *one last thing*. :-)

Comment: Agreed. Hehe :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert to `.exe` I recommend `pyinstaller`.

Do `pip install pyinstaller` and then `cd` to the directory of your project and do `pyinstaller projectname.py`. After that, in the `dist` directory there will be a folder and in it a `.exe` file with the name of your python project. **This will keep all arguments used to run the program.**

After this, add that folder to your PATH and that is it! You can run it from anywhere anytime on the command line now!